# Create a defined function that creates columns into the dataframe based on existing columns

Tags: r, function

I want to create a user defined function that creates multiple columns into the dataframe. The dataframe would be an input to the function.

dataframe (df) has the following columns: A, B, C, D, E, F

```
function_name <- function(df){
 df$new_col1 <- df$A / df$B
 df$new_col2 <- df$C ** df$E
 df$new_col3 <- (df$F + df$B) / df$E
}
```

Once the function is created, I want to be able to feed dataframe df2 which has the same vars as df but different values

Comment: In your function, you just need to return `df` at the end

Comment: Thanks, it works now!